# Impressionist gem database migration failing on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

I am using the [impressionist gem](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) in my app in order to count page-views and it works fine locally. After I push it to Heroku and attempt to view my page live, I receive the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "impressions" does not exist

2017-10-28T05:16:47.366840+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"impressions"'::regclass
2017-10-28T05:16:47.366841+00:00 app[web.1]:                                           ^
```

I have tried to run `heroku run rails db:migrate` and  `heroku restart` but I continue to receive the same error. All my associations are as they should be in my rails models and controllers.

Comment: Did run `heroku run rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: Figured it out. My impressionist migration file was somehow missing from my heroku git repository.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. My impressionist migration file was somehow missing from my heroku git repository. First I had to generate the impressionist migration again to create the table.

```
rails g impressionist
```

migrate it after pushing to heroku:

```
heroku run rails db:migrate
```

Comment: You should describe how you resolved the issue so that others who experience something similar might have a chance of getting it resolved